# CSS to target parent selector but exclude specific children using :not()

Tags: css

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dkmmtpta/6/

This is a barebones example to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. All text within the body renders as helvetica, except for the article class which renders as georgia. However, certain children of article need to be excluded to display as helvetica (as inherited from body, not explicitly set by adding new CSS rules). CSS definition for body class cannot be modified.

I tried excluding the span class using `.article p,.article span:not(.exclude)` but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Is it possible to accomplish this using `:not()`?

Comment: `article, .article:not(.exclude)` will always match all `article`s

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dkmmtpta/4/

Comment: Also, it's the `<span>` that is marked as `.exclude`. Not `article`

Comment: you do not need the :not selector, just use an extra selector to override the .article rule https://jsfiddle.net/dkmmtpta/5/

Comment: Pawel, GCyrillus both solutions work but is there a way to do it without modifying the body CSS definition?

Comment: In that case, the question is unanswerable. There is no CSS rule for inheriting from anything but the parent. So the `.exclude` can only inherit from its parent (`p` in this case) or have a specific font-family set. There is no other option.

Comment: Please put the code, or the relevant portions thereof, directly in the question.

Comment: @Slim, is it okay to modify the html(body css will be unchanged)?

Comment: Can't you just redefine the style of the "tag to exclude" instead of trying to hack the CSS inheritance, like https://jsfiddle.net/dkmmtpta/7/ ?